# How to assign Keycloak Roles to IDP Users

Tags: azure, keycloak, adfs

I am running Keycloak and i have integrated the Azure AD Identity Provider using OIDC.

When i try to get the token for the custom realm i created i can only get the Token if am providing the User Name and Password that is created in KeyCloak. If i use the ADFS uid/pwd i am getting the following
response.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
}
```

The POST Request I am making is as below:

https://<DOMAIN_NAME>/auth/realms/<RELAM_NAME>/protocol/openid-connect/token

and i am passing the following info in Request Headers

```
grant_type = password
client_id  = <CLIENT_NAME_USED_FOR_CLIENT_CREATED_IN_KEYCLOAK>
client_secret = <CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_KEYCLOAK>
username = AD Email
password = AD Password
```

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 0):

You have integrated Keycloak with Azure AD. If you try using ADFS then it will be on on-premises so here ADFS does not fit in.  If you have to use ADFS then keycloak will act as an SP and need to set ADFS as an IDP.